# Trackpad dies after some time

Tags: gnome, mouse, laptop, wayland, trackpad

Running Gnome on an Archlinux system on a Toshiba Z-30 laptop. Over the last couple of mothns I've been encountering a strange issue with the mouse/trackpad. After a couple hours of use, the trackpad starts randomly failing until it dies completely. The only way for it to work again is to either by suspending and logging back in, or completely rebooting the computer. Whenever the trackpad starts failing, there are several "GlidePoint" synchornization error messages:

```
[ 1939.452150] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.
[ 1940.299987] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[ 1944.800748] input: PS/2 ALPS GlidePoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input18
[ 1945.027450] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[ 1949.473934] input: PS/2 ALPS GlidePoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input20
[ 1949.530305] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
```

and when it dies completely there are similar errors:

```
[ 8132.252999] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[ 8132.254181] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 8132.255169] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 8132.258225] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 3
[ 8132.268968] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 8184.809139] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 3
[ 8184.810172] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 8184.813140] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 3
[ 8184.825085] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 8196.016974] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[ 8196.020047] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 3
[ 8196.031029] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 8201.079328] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[ 8201.080373] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 8201.083442] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 3
[ 8201.095585] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 8264.802210] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 4
[ 8264.803244] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 8264.806309] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 3
[ 8264.817217] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 8411.071835] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[ 8411.179994] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 8541.540503] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[ 8541.542427] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 8541.544412] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 3
[ 8541.545407] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[ 8541.556953] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[ 8551.013818] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[ 8551.110465] psmouse serio1: GlidePoint at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
```

What could be causing this issue? I doubt it could be an harware malfunction, as the mouse recovers right away if GNOME restarts.

Comment: Having the exact same issue w/ FreeBSD+XFCE and a Lenovo Ideapad. It got be a hw issue w/ those models of trackpads.

Comment: The touchpad has worked with no issue for roughly 4 years, and it immediately recovers with rebooting/suspending. While it could very well be hardware-related, I really doubt it.

Comment: hw + driver issues I bet.  Some initialization / flaw in the machine state of the open source drivers/interrupt handler. It apparently works wells enough and misbehaves randomly. It returns to working normally upon rebooting/suspending as you describe. Interestingly enough, you are in Linux and I am in FreeBSD 12.

Comment: There are multiple Z30 models. Suggest you collect your serial number and enter it here https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200015974 to see exactly which Z30 you have, then click [edit] and add the model number to your question.

Comment: Could be a stupid [ribbon cable probem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnzjLpvR8YI)? Also reported in the [toshiba  forum](https://forum.toshiba.eu/showthread.php?84484-Portege-Z30-A-191-the-cursor-starts-moving-by-itself&p=336239&viewfull=1#post336239) (read the post below too).